# Postgres starting issue

Tags: postgres.app

I'm having an issue with PostgreSQL

anytime I run

```
psql -h localhost
```

I get

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. First make sure PostgreSQL server has been started to remote server.

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

If it is running and you get above error, you need to add enable TCP/IP support. By default, the PostgreSQL server only allows connections to the database from the local machine or localhost. This is a security feature.

**Step # 1: Allow remote IP address to access PostgreSQL**

You need to open file called /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf. Login as postgres user using su command:

```
$ su - postgres
$ vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Now append following line. Let us say you would like to give access to 192.168.1.0/24 network:

```
host all all 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 trust
```

Please replace 192.168.1.0 and 255.255.255.0 to reflect the actual network IP address range of the clients system in your own network.

Save close the file.

**Step # 2: Allow communication over TCP/IP**

You need to open PostgreSQL configuration file /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf

```
$ vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Now bind and open TCP/IP port by setting tcpip_socket to true:

```
tcpip_socket = true
```

Save and close the file.

**Step # 3: Restart PostgreSQL server**

Restart the PostgreSQL server with the following command

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

This will open default port 5432.

Step # 4: Test your setup

Use psql command from client system as follows:

```
psql -h PostgreSQL-IP-ADDRESS -U USERNAME -d DATABASENAME
```

Connect to remote server by IP address 192.168.1.5 and login using vivek user to connect to sales database, use:

```
$ psql -h 192.168.1.5 -U vivek -d sales
```

Where,

> **-h 192.168.1.5 :** Specifies the host name of the machine or IP address (192.168.1.5) on which the server is running.
>
> **-U vivek :** Connect to the database as the vivek username instead of the default. You must have account and permission to connect as vivek user.
>
> **-d sales :** Specifies the name of the database (sales) to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this and using Postgres.app, you may need host: localhost in your database.yml. http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_3